# Java - How to pass arguments through a shortcut

Tags: java, windows, arguments, shortcut

I have a java program that starts at a normal *public static void main(String[] args)*

I want to be able to create shortcuts to this program (just right-click at the executable in a folder, press Create Shortcut) and then be able to pass along an argument which will end up in the *String[] args*

It matters little exactly what this argument actually IS, since the sole purpose I want this for is so that I can create 2 shortcuts to the same program, and put one in Window's Auto-start Folder and the other on the desktop. The former simply shall run in the background every time I start the computer, while the other shall actually open a window so that I can manage the program settings.

Essentially; I just want to have 2 Windows Shortcuts where one makes **args[0].equals("X")** and the other makes **args[0].equals("Y")**. How do I make this happen?

Comment: Do you want to create this shortcut manually or by code ?

Comment: You can write a bash script and create a shortcut that executes it, though you would probably need two separate scripts.

Comment: @Nexevis bash will be difficult on Windows ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool you can try if you're releasing your program on Windows. 
Or if you prefer to handle it yourself, you could use two separate `.bat` files and put them within the same folder with your main `.jar` file. Then the shortcuts should point to each of the `.bat` files, but one thing you should consider is to set the PATH variable to include JRE. or to use the full path to the `java.exe`.

for example,
say that you have your program as `MyApp.jar` located at `C:/Users/user1/MyApp/`
with `foo.bat` in the same folder it should be something like this:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar X
```

`bar.bat` in the same folder as well:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar Y
```

that's if JRE is included in the PATH variable, otherwise, you have to replace 
`java` command with the full path to `java.exe` so it becomes something like:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_212\\java.exe" -jar MyApp.jar YOUR_ARGUMENT
```

Notice the double quotes are required here because the path includes spaces, and of course, the JRE path varies depending on the version and the architecture of Windows sometimes it is in `Progam Files (x86)`.

Also, you need to figure out a way to hide the console window that popups up after starting the `.bat` file, console windows will stay visible until your java program terminates and if the user closes them, that will kill your program. [this](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php) may be helpful.

Comment: A lot of this is interesting, but if I have to have 2 different files (in this case .bat files) in addition to the .jar file I might as well just compile 2 .jar files and use one for each "state" of the program.